# mysql: database and table names as unicode

Tags: mysql, unicode

I couldn't find any information about that in the docs.

Is mySQL supports UNICODE characters in the database or table name? As an example - can I create a database and use Russian or Chinese to name the database?

If it is supported, how do I connect to such db? I.e. should I set up some option either in configuiration file or in the code (Connector/C)?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: To interpret the doc -- Russian and _most_ of Chinese is supported.